# Insertion of keyboard IRPs via Keyboard filter driver under Windows OS

Tags: windows, keyboard, driver, wdk

I'm trying to insert keyboard keypress events from the driver level under Windows 10 OS.

I'm using kbfiltr driver sample for my experiments. And right now I've implemented a custom IOCTL that delivers the event to the kbfiltr IRP queue handler where I'm trying to inject a KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA entity to the KBDClass driver queue by invoking ServiceCallback routine of the KBDClass driver. And it seems to produce no errors, but it also doesn't produce any key presses.

I also tried to insert additional key press event alongside with normal keyboard events: add additional KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA to the queue passed to the ServiceCallback routine by the keyboard driver and it worked perfectly.

I saw suggestions to use VHIDmini2 sample, but I also need to intercept certain keypresses, so it's not really an option for me.

I can compare two flows in order to understand the difference but is seems like not really trivial reverse engineering task under Windows. So, I wonder maybe there is a known solution or maybe someone might have an idea on what I'm doing wrong or maybe there is a keyboard driver with open source that I can use as reference for my experiments?

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U97PGO_7mgSO_kLu1mhCVC7ZeLOm0DWB/view?usp=sharing here is my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the [service callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/kbdmou/nc-kbdmou-pservice_callback_routine) correctly:

> InputDataEnd [in]
>
> Pointer to the keyboard input data packet that **immediately follows** the last data packet in the input data buffer.

You need to call it like this:

```
(*(PSERVICE_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)(ULONG_PTR)devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassService)(
        devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassDeviceObject,
        &kbd_dt,
        &kbd_dt + 1,
        &consumed);
```